# How to disable a UINavigationBarItem?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uikit, uinavigationcontroller

I'm trying to disable a button that I add to my navigation controller bar. Here is how I added it:

```
UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Add" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(addNew)];          
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
[addButton release];
```

What is the best way to enable/disable items like these? I've tried this code:

```
addButton.disabled = YES;
```

but it doesn't work of course. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Edit: Should be addButton.enabled = YES;

Oops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define `addButton` in your header, and @synthesize it, then you will be able to use `addButton.enabled = NO;`, there is no "disabled" setter.

### .h

```
@interface MyViewController {
    UIBarButtonItem *addButton;
}
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIBarButtonItem *addButton;
@end
```

### .m

```
@implementation MyViewController
@synthesize addButton;

-(void)viewDidLoad{
    addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Add" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(addNew)];          
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
    [addButton release];
}
-(void)DoSomething{
    addButton.enabled = NO;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've lost my mind. I don't know why in the world I put disabled. I've been coding too long today, it looks like I need to take a break. :-) Thanks